# gradle - Build ear from dependent projects in nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

I have the project dependencies stored in nexus repository. Let's say I have a three projects A, B and C, all these are built as WAR and stored in nexus. I would like to have a project D  which should be built as an EAR file, consisting of all the three projects (A, B and C).  Is this possible without again creating sub projects(A, B and C) inside D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to configure a repository to download the artifacts and dependencies in `build.gradle` where `ear` plugin is applied:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
  deploy 'lol:lol:1.0'
}
```

Have a look at the demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46675757). First run `gradle publishToMavenLocal` and then `gradle -b ear.gradle build`. Under `build/libs` and `*.ear` file can be found.

Comment: Thanks !, that works, but ear contains the jar instead of war.  Do I have to specify anything here to say to pick the war instead of jar ..

Comment: @JosephMartin, no not specifically. Ming that in `war` projects only `war` plugin is applied (I mean no `java`) - maybe it has sth to do with this.